# How to get selected nodes when dynatree is loaded using persistence

Tags: jquery, dynatree

Using persistence with dynatree, when the tree is re-loaded, I want to get all selected nodes, in order to send them in a request. How can I do that ? I've only found a way to get selected nodes with the onSelect event.

Answer (score 9):

This will return all selected nodes :

```
var selKeys = $.map($("#tree").dynatree("getSelectedNodes"), function(node) {
                            return node.data.key;
                        });
```